# multiple facebutton button like with different values

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to have multiple og:title(etc) in a page?

I have 4 different products on same page (url: site/#theblock)
I want my users to share the product with the correct link on their FB.

I tried jquery but its not working.
Im using a wordpress cms.

Any idea how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some server side technology to dynamically change the og tags based on query string parameters.  Hash tags will not work since they are only used by the browser and are not sent to the server.

The reason to set the og tags server side is because Facebook's scraper does not run JavaScript and therefore your server needs to make the correct tags upon serving the page.